# parsing XML data in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle11g

I am new to oracle XML area. i am trying to parse an XML, but failing to do.

Below is the XML data.

---

```
<CompositeDataObject Type="ApplicantsAAT" Version="0">
<DataObjectElement SystemName="AccountRelationship" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection">
<CollectionItem ID="604008" EncryptedID="4GnX1!b8epwsAmwbfvZjo;xAAAAAB6r2wy" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="AccountRelationshipAAT"/>
<CollectionItem ID="604040" EncryptedID="4IrPkqeoo7EVLEuSm7egK96AAAAAB6r2zS" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="AccountRelationshipAAT"/>
</DataObjectElement>
<DataObjectElement SystemName="ApplicantCreditRefDetailsAATSL" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603979" EncryptedID="4PPEFaEyt2Q!K48f13wy7gzAAAAAB6r2wR" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="ApplicantCreditRefDetailsAATSL"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="CreditCardsTPF" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><CompositeDataObjectElement SystemName="CreditObligations" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="CreditScoring" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603970" EncryptedID="4CWx;PRGqbV1IMzP4DtnY2IAAAAAB6r2wY" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="CreditScoring"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="DependantDetails" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603978" EncryptedID="4OReRldXZeF8IU9a2e3RZk9AAAAAB6r2wQ" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="ApplicantDependantDetailsAATSL"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="EmploymentAATSL" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603972" EncryptedID="4GkF83Ll!xLiLqS1zL;FMG4AAAAAB6r2we" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="EmploymentAperioOnlyAATSL"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="ExpenditureDetailsTPF" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603980" EncryptedID="4G6EGC6aL8LmN94xr9LNgRxAAAAAB6r2wW" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="ExpenditureTPF"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="Fields" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="9251" EncryptedID="4MEw5;;AiwprG2uKYJGudrLAAAAAB6pn95" DataObjectCategory="Party" DataObjectType="Personal"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="FinancialAssetsAATSL" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="FinancialExpenseAATSL" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="FinancialLiabilitiesAATSL" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="FinancierDeductionAATSL" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="IncomeSalariedAATSL" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603973" EncryptedID="4J04bAAaMKqPIXbr7AAUfoQAAAAAB6r2wf" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="ApplicantFinancialIncomeSalariedFinalAATSL"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="IncomeSelfEmployedAATSL" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603974" EncryptedID="4D;pvvFrYPDyLjkipR7sYyQAAAAAB6r2wc" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="ApplicantFinancialIncomeSelfEmplAATAP"/>
<CompositeDataObjectElement SystemName="Tabs" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="378409" EncryptedID="4J!pTqS7x4XxIYZjRd2jA2UAAAAAB6o51z" CompositeDataObject="ApplicantsViewsAAT"/>
</CompositeDataObject>
```

---

The below query works fine if  the `CollectionItem` exists only one time inside `DataObjectElement`.  If `collectionItem` appears more then once, it fails. 
Basically what I am trying to achieve is consider data into new row whenever it see an TAG ID.

---

```
 WITH t AS (SELECT XMLType('<CompositeDataObject Type="ApplicantsAAT" Version="0">
<DataObjectElement SystemName="AccountRelationship" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection">
<CollectionItem ID="604008" EncryptedID="4GnX1!b8epwsAmwbfvZjo;xAAAAAB6r2wy" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="AccountRelationshipAAT"/>
<CollectionItem ID="604040" EncryptedID="4IrPkqeoo7EVLEuSm7egK96AAAAAB6r2zS" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="AccountRelationshipAAT"/>
</DataObjectElement>
<DataObjectElement SystemName="ApplicantCreditRefDetailsAATSL" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603979" EncryptedID="4PPEFaEyt2Q!K48f13wy7gzAAAAAB6r2wR" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="ApplicantCreditRefDetailsAATSL"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="CreditCardsTPF" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><CompositeDataObjectElement SystemName="CreditObligations" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="CreditScoring" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603970" EncryptedID="4CWx;PRGqbV1IMzP4DtnY2IAAAAAB6r2wY" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="CreditScoring"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="DependantDetails" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603978" EncryptedID="4OReRldXZeF8IU9a2e3RZk9AAAAAB6r2wQ" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="ApplicantDependantDetailsAATSL"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="EmploymentAATSL" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603972" EncryptedID="4GkF83Ll!xLiLqS1zL;FMG4AAAAAB6r2we" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="EmploymentAperioOnlyAATSL"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="ExpenditureDetailsTPF" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603980" EncryptedID="4G6EGC6aL8LmN94xr9LNgRxAAAAAB6r2wW" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="ExpenditureTPF"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="Fields" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="9251" EncryptedID="4MEw5;;AiwprG2uKYJGudrLAAAAAB6pn95" DataObjectCategory="Party" DataObjectType="Personal"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="FinancialAssetsAATSL" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="FinancialExpenseAATSL" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="FinancialLiabilitiesAATSL" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="FinancierDeductionAATSL" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="IncomeSalariedAATSL" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603973" EncryptedID="4J04bAAaMKqPIXbr7AAUfoQAAAAAB6r2wf" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="ApplicantFinancialIncomeSalariedFinalAATSL"/><DataObjectElement SystemName="IncomeSelfEmployedAATSL" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603974" EncryptedID="4D;pvvFrYPDyLjkipR7sYyQAAAAAB6r2wc" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="ApplicantFinancialIncomeSelfEmplAATAP"/>
<CompositeDataObjectElement SystemName="Tabs" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="378409" EncryptedID="4J!pTqS7x4XxIYZjRd2jA2UAAAAAB6o51z" CompositeDataObject="ApplicantsViewsAAT"/>
</CompositeDataObject>') xmlcol
               FROM dual)
    SELECT extract(value(x),'//*[@ID]/@ID') linked_object_id,
    extractValue(value(x),'//*[@ID]/ancestor-or-self::*[@EncryptedID]/@EncryptedID') linked_object_encrypted_id,
    extractValue(value(x),'//*[@ID]/ancestor-or-self::*[@SystemName]/@SystemName') system_name,
    extractValue(value(x),'//*[@ID]/ancestor-or-self::*[@DataObjectCategory]/@DataObjectCategory') data_object_category,
    extractValue(value(x),'//*[@ID]/ancestor-or-self::*[@ObjectType]/@ObjectType') object_type,
    extractValue(value(x),'//*[@ID]/ancestor-or-self::*[@DataObjectType]/@DataObjectType') data_object_type,
     extractValue(value(x),'//*[@ID]/ancestor-or-self::*[@CompositeDataObject]/@CompositeDataObject') composite_data_object
    FROM t, TABLE(XMLSequence(extract(t.xmlcol,'/CompositeDataObject/*'))) x;
```

=====================================
Below is the simple example which i am expecting

Thanks for your valuable reply.

the query you posted works fine. but as you can see there are some fields which are generated NULL. 
for instance. 1st DataObjectElement contains 2 CollectionItem(604008,604008a) but there is no "SystemName" with in CollectionItem so i am expecting 
SystemName from the main DataObjectElement tag.. which is "AccountRelationship".
same goes to ObjectType

```
WITH t AS (SELECT XMLType('<CompositeDataObject Type="ApplicantsAAT" Version="0">
<DataObjectElement SystemName="AccountRelationship" ObjectType="DataObjectCollection">
<CollectionItem ID="604008" EncryptedID="4GnX1!b8epwsAmwbfvZjo;xAAAAAB6r2wy" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="AccountRelationshipAAT"/>
<CollectionItem ID="604008a" EncryptedID="4GnX1!b8epwsAmwbfvZjo;xAAAAAB6r2wy" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="AccountRelationshipAAT"/>
</DataObjectElement>
<DataObjectElement SystemName="ApplicantCreditRefDetailsAATSL" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="603979" EncryptedID="4PPEFaEyt2Q!K48f13wy7gzAAAAAB6r2wR" DataObjectCategory="RepeatingAttribute" DataObjectType="ApplicantCreditRefDetailsAATSL"/>
<CompositeDataObjectElement SystemName="Tabs" ObjectType="DataObject" ID="378409" EncryptedID="4J!pTqS7x4XxIYZjRd2jA2UAAAAAB6o51z" CompositeDataObject="ApplicantsViewsAAT"/>
</CompositeDataObject>') xmlcol
               FROM dual)

                 SELECT extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@ID') id,
              extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@EncryptedID') EncryptedID,
              extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@SystemName') SystemName,
              extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@DataObjectCategory') DataObjectCategory,
              extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@ObjectType') ObjectType,
              extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@DataObjectType') DataObjectType,
              extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@CompositeDataObject') CompositeDataObject
       FROM t, TABLE(XMLSequence(extract(t.xmlcol,'//*[@ID]'))) x;
```

The result from the above query is

```
ID      ENCRYPTEDID                         SYSTEMNAME                      DATAOBJECTCATEGORY  OBJECTTYPE              DATAOBJECTTYPE                  COMPOSITEDATAOBJECT
604008  4GnX1!b8epwsAmwbfvZjo;xAAAAAB6r2wy                                  RepeatingAttribute                          AccountRelationshipAAT  
604008a 4GnX1!b8epwsAmwbfvZjo;xAAAAAB6r2wy                                  RepeatingAttribute                          AccountRelationshipAAT  
603979  4PPEFaEyt2Q!K48f13wy7gzAAAAAB6r2wR  ApplicantCreditRefDetailsAATSL  RepeatingAttribute  DataObject  ApplicantCreditRefDetailsAATSL  
378409  4J!pTqS7x4XxIYZjRd2jA2UAAAAAB6o51z  Tabs                                                DataObject                                                                              ApplicantsViewsAAT
```

just slight change i am expecting is ( below result contains value for SYSTEMNAME AND OBJECTTYPE)

```
ID      ENCRYPTEDID                         SYSTEMNAME                      DATAOBJECTCATEGORY  OBJECTTYPE              DATAOBJECTTYPE                  COMPOSITEDATAOBJECT
604008  4GnX1!b8epwsAmwbfvZjo;xAAAAAB6r2wy  AccountRelationship             RepeatingAttribute  DataObjectCollection    AccountRelationshipAAT  
604008a 4GnX1!b8epwsAmwbfvZjo;xAAAAAB6r2wy  AccountRelationship             RepeatingAttribute  DataObjectCollection    AccountRelationshipAAT  
603979  4PPEFaEyt2Q!K48f13wy7gzAAAAAB6r2wR  ApplicantCreditRefDetailsAATSL  RepeatingAttribute  DataObject  ApplicantCreditRefDetailsAATSL  
378409  4J!pTqS7x4XxIYZjRd2jA2UAAAAAB6o51z  Tabs                                                DataObject                                                                              ApplicantsViewsAAT
```

pleases copy past my content into some textpad for clearer view. 
your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

im not totally sure what you're after but is it 1 row per "id"? if so..

```
 10  select id, EncryptedID,
 11         nvl(SystemName, extractvalue(xmlcol, '//*[child::*/@ID="' || id || '"]/@SystemName')) SystemName,
 12         DataObjectCategory,
 13         nvl(ObjectType, extractvalue(xmlcol, '//*[child::*/@ID="' || id || '"]/@ObjectType')) ObjectType,
 14         DataObjectType,
 15         CompositeDataObject
 16    from (SELECT t.xmlcol, extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@ID') id,
 17                 extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@EncryptedID') EncryptedID,
 18                 extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@SystemName') SystemName,
 19                 extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@DataObjectCategory') DataObjectCategory,
 20                 extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@ObjectType') ObjectType,
 21                 extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@DataObjectType') DataObjectType,
 22                 extractvalue(value(x), '/*/@CompositeDataObject') CompositeDataObject
 23          FROM t, TABLE(XMLSequence(extract(t.xmlcol,'//*[@ID]'))) x)
 24  ;

ID         ENCRYPTEDID          SYSTEMNAME           DATAOBJECTCATEGORY   OBJECTTYPE           DATAOBJECTTYPE       COMPOSITEDATAOBJECT
---------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
604008     4GnX1!b8epwsAmwbfvZj AccountRelationship  RepeatingAttribute   DataObjectCollection AccountRelationshipA
           o;xAAAAAB6r2wy                                                                      AT

604040     4IrPkqeoo7EVLEuSm7eg AccountRelationship  RepeatingAttribute   DataObjectCollection AccountRelationshipA
           K96AAAAAB6r2zS                                                                      AT

603979     4PPEFaEyt2Q!K48f13wy ApplicantCreditRefDe RepeatingAttribute   DataObject           ApplicantCreditRefDe
           7gzAAAAAB6r2wR       tailsAATSL                                                     tailsAATSL

603970     4CWx;PRGqbV1IMzP4Dtn CreditScoring        RepeatingAttribute   DataObject           CreditScoring
           Y2IAAAAAB6r2wY

603978     4OReRldXZeF8IU9a2e3R DependantDetails     RepeatingAttribute   DataObject           ApplicantDependantDe
           Zk9AAAAAB6r2wQ                                                                      tailsAATSL

603972     4GkF83Ll!xLiLqS1zL;F EmploymentAATSL      RepeatingAttribute   DataObject           EmploymentAperioOnly
           MG4AAAAAB6r2we                                                                      AATSL

603980     4G6EGC6aL8LmN94xr9LN ExpenditureDetailsTP RepeatingAttribute   DataObject           ExpenditureTPF
           gRxAAAAAB6r2wW       F

9251       4MEw5;;AiwprG2uKYJGu Fields               Party                DataObject           Personal
           drLAAAAAB6pn95

603973     4J04bAAaMKqPIXbr7AAU IncomeSalariedAATSL  RepeatingAttribute   DataObject           ApplicantFinancialIn
           foQAAAAAB6r2wf                                                                      comeSalariedFinalAAT
                                                                                               SL

603974     4D;pvvFrYPDyLjkipR7s IncomeSelfEmployedAA RepeatingAttribute   DataObject           ApplicantFinancialIn
           YyQAAAAAB6r2wc       TSL                                                            comeSelfEmplAATAP

378409     4J!pTqS7x4XxIYZjRd2j Tabs                                      DataObject                                ApplicantsViewsAAT
           A2UAAAAAB6o51z
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply. a slight change i am expecting in the above query to get SystemName and ObjectType.
the query you posted works fine. but as you can see there are some fields(SystemName and ObjectType) which are generated NULL. 
for instance. 1st DataObjectElement contains 2 CollectionItem(604008,604008a) but there is no "SystemName" with in CollectionItem so i am expecting 
SystemName from the main DataObjectElement tag.. which is "AccountRelationship".
same goes to ObjectType

Comment: could someone help me on the above query please

Comment: @Arkesh no prob. please accept the answer if this is all done now